# Uninstall all packages installed on a certain day in synaptic

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, synaptic

Today I installed the package **maven** on my system. Unfortunately its the wrong version. Now I'd like to uninstall all packages that were installed as dependencies. Do I have to uninstall them manually? or is there a way to uninstall all packages that were installed for maven?

```
grep install /var/log/dpkg.log
```

tells me, that its quite a lot of packages,...

```
2015-01-11 20:20:15 status installed man-db:amd64 2.7.0.2-2
2015-01-11 20:20:15 status installed doc-base:all 0.10.6
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libyaml-snake-java:all 1.12-2
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java:all 1.2-7build1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libxml-commons-external-java:all 1.4.01-2build1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libxerces2-java:all 2.11.0-7
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed ant:all 1.9.4-1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed ant-optional:all 1.9.4-1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libaspectj-java:all 1.6.12+dfsg-3
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed aspectj:all 1.6.12+dfsg-3
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libjline-java:all 1.0-2
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libbsh-java:all 2.0b4-15
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed bsh:all 2.0b4-15
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libjaxp1.3-java:all 1.3.05-2ubuntu3
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libxalan2-java:all 2.7.1-9
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libapache-pom-java:all 10-2build1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libbsf-java:all 1:2.4.0-5build1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libavalon-framework-java:all 4.2.0-9
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libcommons-io-java:all 2.4-2
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libcommons-parent-java:all 22-2build1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libcommons-logging-java:all 1.2-1ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed java-wrappers:all 0.1.28
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libbatik-java:all 1.7.ubuntu-8ubuntu2
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libxmlgraphics-commons-java:all 1.5-4ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libfop-java:all 1:1.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed fop:all 1:1.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed junit:all 3.8.2-8build1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libhamcrest-java:all 1.3-5ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed junit4:all 4.11-3
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libnetty-java:all 1:3.2.6.Final-2
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libslf4j-java:all 1.7.6-1
2015-01-11 20:20:16 status installed libasync-http-client-java:all 1.6.5-2
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-classworlds2-java:all 2.5.1-2
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libasm3-java:all 3.3.2-2
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libcommons-lang-java:all 2.6-3ubuntu2
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libcommons-cli-java:all 1.2-3ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libatinject-jsr330-api-java:all 1.0+ds1-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libjsr305-java:all 0.1~+svn49-4
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libguava-java:all 17.0-1ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libjaxen-java:all 1.1.6-1ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libjdom1-java:all 1.1.3-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libclassworlds-java:all 1.1-final-5
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libservlet3.0-java:all 7.0.55-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libcommons-configuration-java:all 1.10-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libcommons-codec-java:all 1.9-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libhttpcore-java:all 4.3.2-2
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libhttpclient-java:all 4.3.4-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libitext1-java:all 1.4-5
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed liblog4j1.2-java:all 1.2.17-4ubuntu3
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-interpolation-java:all 1.19-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-utils-java:all 1:1.5.15-4
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-container-default-java:all 1.0-alpha-9-stable-1-7
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-classworlds-java:all 1.5.0-5
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libxbean-java:all 3.7-6
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-containers-java:all 1.0~beta3.0.7-7
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-i18n-java:all 1.0-beta-10-3
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libdoxia-java:all 1.1.4-1ubuntu4
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-build-api-java:all 0.0.7-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libmodello-java:all 1.1-3
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-ant-factory-java:all 1.0~alpha2.1-3
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-io-java:all 1.0~alpha5-2
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-archiver-java:all 1.2-1
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-bsh-factory-java:all 1.0~alpha7-3
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-interactivity-api-java:all 1.0-alpha-6-7
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-cipher-java:all 1.5-4
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java:all 1.3.1-6
2015-01-11 20:20:17 status installed libcommons-httpclient-java:all 3.1-10.2
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcommons-net2-java:all 2.2-2
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcglib-java:all 2.2.2+dfsg2-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libobjenesis-java:all 1.2+full-3
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libeasymock-java:all 3.2+ds-2
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libservlet2.5-java:all 6.0.41-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libjetty-java:all 6.1.26-3
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libjsch-java:all 0.1.51-1ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libjsoup-java:all 1.7.3-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libganymed-ssh2-java:all 250-2
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libnetbeans-cvsclient-java:all 6.5-2
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libregexp-java:all 1.5-3build1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libplexus-cli-java:all 1.2-5
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libplexus-utils2-java:all 2.0.5-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libqdox-java:all 1.12-1build1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libaopalliance-java:all 20070526-5
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java:all 1.0.1-1fakesync1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcdi-api-java:all 1.0-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libsisu-guice-java:all 3.2.2+dfsg-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcommons-collections3-java:all 3.2.1-7
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcommons-beanutils-java:all 1.9.2-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcommons-digester-java:all 1.8.1-4
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcommons-jexl2-java:all 2.1.1-2
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcommons-jxpath-java:all 1.3-6
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libcommons-vfs-java:all 2.0-3ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libxpp2-java:all 2.1.10-7build1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libxpp3-java:all 1.1.4c-2build1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libdom4j-java:all 1.6.1+dfsg.3-2ubuntu1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libosgi-core-java:all 4.3.1-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libosgi-foundation-ee-java:all 4.2.0-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libguice-java:all 3.0-3
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libjackrabbit-java:all 2.3.6-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libjcommander-java:all 1.32-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libjsch-agent-proxy-java:all 0.0.7-1
2015-01-11 20:20:18 status installed libmaven-parent-java:all 21-2
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed librhino-java:all 1.7R4-3
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libsaxon-java:all 1:6.5.5-10
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libxom-java:all 1.2.10-1
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed rhino:all 1.7R4-3
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed testng:all 6.8.8-2
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libosgi-compendium-java:all 4.3.0-1
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libgeronimo-osgi-support-java:all 1.0-2
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libwagon-java:all 1.0.0-2ubuntu2
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java:all 1.1-2
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libmaven2-core-java:all 2.2.1-15
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libmaven-scm-java:all 1.3-5
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libplexus-containers1.5-java:all 1.5.5-6
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libsisu-ioc-java:all 2.3.0-5
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libaether-java:all 1.13.1-2
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed libwagon2-java:all 2.6-1.1
2015-01-11 20:20:19 status installed maven:all 3.0.5-1
```

Comment: After removing maven with `sudo apt-get remove maven` try `sudo apt-get autoremove`. This removes all packages were installed due to dependencies, but the package that depend on them was removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependencies (and configuration files if you ran the application) can be automatically removed by issuing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove maven
sudo apt-get purge
```

if you want to erase old downloaded archive files as well, do an:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

after that you should be able to safely install maven2...